# How to crop just 2 pixels without re-encoding (H264 video)?

Tags: ffmpeg, aspect, bluray

I just want to crop 2 pixels (Top) to get identical black bars (now is 138 TOP and 140 BOTTOM) but without re-encoding. I think it is possible with FFmpeg but I'm not sure. I want to do this with one H264 video (m2ts from blu-ray).

Comment: This is impossible without re-encoding. Chillax. No-one will die if you re-encode your video.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [h264_metadata](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#h264_005fmetadata) bitstream filter.

```
ffmpeg -i in -c copy -bsf:v h264_metadata=crop_top=140 out
```